# Is there a PHP function to get a human readable difference between two timestamps by adapting if it is after or before the current date?

Tags: php, function, date, time, timestamp

There is a PHP function to get a human readable difference between two timestamps by adapting if it is after or before the current date? For example:

***Current date: 1668872288 (2022-11-19 16:38:08)***

```js
since_or_in_func('1474475346') // (2016-09-21 16:29:06) return 5 year, ... hour, min etc. ago
since_or_in_func('1790807854') // (2026-09-30 22:37:34) return In 4 year, ... hour, min etc.
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Not exactly, but [DateTimeInterface::diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) will get you close.

Comment: Found [1](https://github.com/pear/Date_HumanDiff), [2](https://github.com/danielstjules/php-pretty-datetime), [3](https://gist.github.com/ozh/8169202) on GitHub and a lot more.

Comment: You can use the carbon library: echo Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1474475346)->diffForHumans();  //6 years ago